# Which would be better table structure considering - faster execution and optimal structure?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-design

I am implementing **multi-login system** in a web application in Laravel. In the application a user can register with multiple social platforms and all those accounts should be considered as one.

I have 2 ways to implement this:

**Method I:**

```
users table
 - id
 - username
 - email
 - google_id
 - facebook_id
 - github_id
 - twitter_id
 - ...other columns
```

Setting all google_id, facebook_id, twitter_id by default `NULL`. Saving each value based on when user registers with that platform through the application.

**Method II:**

```
users table
    id
    username
    email
    .. other columns

social-login table
    id
    user_id
    social_type //facebook or google or twitter etc
    uid         // unique identifier returned from each platform
```

Using **Method I**, I am getting better performance as I need to execute queries just on one table but **method II** is providing better table structure.

Which method should I use? Consider the fact that there would lot of requests and in all requests we are going to get `uid` and not `user_id` to fetch any information of the user.

The queries would be something like below:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=2;
SELECT * FROM `social-login` WHERE user_id=2;
SELECT * FROM users as U JOIN `social-login` as S ON S.user_id=U.id WHERE U.id=2
```

Comment: Relational database first normal form forbids the use of inapplicable NULLs so in order to have a normalized database you will need to use Method II. Normalization helps prevent data inconsistencies and update anomalies. However, normalization also hurts performance which is why data is often denormalized to improve performance with the drawback of occasionally having inconsistent data. This being said, be very careful not to fall victim of  premature optimization. If you break normalization to make code that normally runs in 2 seconds to run in 1.95 seconds, you gained nothing

Comment: Avoid special characters in table names (etc).  Consider `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, social_type)` and toss `id` for `social_login`.  And use Method II.  You would be adding TikTok, then removing it and adding more columns -- too much bother.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with option 2.

Reasons

1. You could always "add new social types without changing the schema." whereas in 1st option you would have to add another column for that `social_type`.
2. **Normalized database** as it prevents data inconsistencies.

I'd like to add one more suggestion.

Create another table

```
social_type table
id  |   name
1      Facebook
2      Google
```

And refer it's id in the social-login table

```
id   | user_id | social_type_id | uuid
```

Benefits

1. The database has control over the types. With this user can only choose options that exist in the system and are valid for the system. So basically you control it. Whereas earlier user could send any random value `qawqdq` (no doubt that you could have other checks) and it would store it.
2. With the previous approach, there might be a possibility that some rows might have "facebook" in lowercase, some "FACEBOOK" in upper case, some "FaceBook". So this helps in keeping one particular value across all the entries.

Again, performance would be affected by this as it would add an extra join. So it's completely optional. I'd suggest you do it this way if performance is not affected by a huge amount and is not that big of a concern to you.

Comment: Why do you think the first approach is not better?

Comment: Which first approach? Your method 1 Or the first approach that i stated in my solution?

Comment: If it's about your method 1, then read the comment by apokryfos to your post as well as the first point in my reasons(`You could always add new social types without changing the schema. Whereas in 1st option you would have to add another column for that social_type`). And if it's about my first approach, I've already listed the benefits of the second approach in the solution. And as I said earlier, this should be used in case the performance is not affected by a huge amount and performance is not that big of a concern to you.

Answer (score 2):

I would choose **option 2.**

1. It is the cleaner structure
2. You can store the data better

I don't think that the time loss can be that problematic for your performance. I would only choose **option 1** if the time loss is significantly high.